# Java Stream API with non-pure functions chain

Tags: java, java-stream

Let's assume I have a class Person

```java
public class Person {
    private final String name;
    private final int age;
    private boolean rejected;
    private String rejectionComment;

    public void reject(String comment) {
        this.rejected = true;
        this.rejectionComment = comment;
    }

    // constructor & getters are ommited
}
```

and my app is something like that

```java
class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Person> persons = Arrays.asList(
            new Person("John", 10),
            new Person("Sarah", 20),
            new Person("Daniel", 30)
        )

        persons.forEach(p -> {
            rejectIfYoungerThan15(p);
            rejectIfNameStartsWithD(p);
            // other rejection functions
        }
    }

    private static void rejectIfYoungerThan15(Person p) {
        if (!p.isRejected() && p.getAge() < 15) {
            p.reject("Too young")
        }
    }

    private static void rejectIfNameStartsWithD(Person p) {
        if (!p.isRejected() && p.getName().startsWith("D")) {
            p.reject("Name starts with 'D'")
        }
    }

    // other rejection functions
}
```

The thing is I don't like that I have to perform `!p.isRejected()` check in every rejection function. Moreover, it doesn't make sense to pass an already rejected person to next filters.
So my idea is to use a mechanism of `Stream.filter` and make something like

```java
persons.stream().filter(this::rejectIfYoungerThan15).filter(this::rejectIfNameStartsWithD)...
```

And change signature for these methods to return `true` if a passed `Person` has not been rejected and `false` otherwise.

But it seems to me that it's a very bad idea to use `filter` with non-pure functions.

Do you have any ideas of how to make it in more elegant way?

Comment: Can you combine both methods?

Comment: What if one of the input was `new Person("Boris", 12),`, what would be the comment for this person? Or even in your question for `John`. What do you expect the output to be?

Answer (score 1):

When you change the check functions to only check the condition (i.e. not to call `p.isRejected()`) and return `boolean`, you already made the necessary steps to short-circuit:

```
private static boolean rejectIfYoungerThan15(Person p) {
    if(p.getAge() < 15) {
        p.reject("Too young");
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

private static boolean rejectIfNameStartsWithD(Person p) {
    if(p.getName().startsWith("D")) {
        p.reject("Name starts with 'D'");
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

usable as

```
   persons.forEach(p -> {
        if(rejectIfYoungerThan15(p)) return;
        if(rejectIfNameStartsWithD(p)) return;
        // other rejection functions
    }
}
```

A Stream’s `filter` operation wouldn’t do anything other than checking the returned `boolean` value and bail out. But depending on the Stream’s actual terminal operation the short-circuiting could go even farther and end up in not checking all elements, so you should not bring in a Stream operation here.

Answer (score 0):

Calling these methods from lambda is fine, however, for better readability, you can rename these methods to show what they are doing and return `boolean`, e.g.:

```
private boolean hasEligibleAge(Person p){..}
private boolean hasValidName(Person p){..}
```

Another approach would be to wrap these methods into another method (to reflect the business logic/flow), e.g.:

```
private boolean isEligible(Person p){
    //check age
    //check name
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should make `Person` immutable, and let the reject-methods return a new `Person`. That will allow you to chain `map`-calls. Something like this:

```
public class Person {
    private final String name;
    private final int age;
    private final boolean rejected;
    private final String rejectionComment;

    public Person reject(String comment) {
        return new Person(name, age, true, comment);
    }

    // ...

}

class App {

    // ...

    private static Person rejectIfYoungerThan15(Person p) {
        if (!p.isRejected() && p.getAge() < 15) {
            return p.reject("Too young");
        }
        return p;
    }
}
```

Now you can do this:

```
persons.stream()
       .map(App::rejectIfYoungerThan15)
       .map(App::rejectIfNameStartsWithD)
       .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If you want to remove rejected persons, you can add a filter after the mapping:

```
.filter(person -> !person.isRejected())
```

EDIT:

If you need to short circuit the rejections, you could compose your rejection functions into a new function and make it stop after the first rejection. Something like this:

```
/* Remember that the stream is lazy, so it will only call new rejections 
 * while the person isn't rejected.
 */
public Function<Person, Person> shortCircuitReject(List<Function<Person, Person>> rejections) {
    return person -> rejections.stream()
            .map(rejection -> rejection.apply(person))
            .filter(Person::isRejected)
            .findFirst()
            .orElse(person);
}
```

Now your stream can look like this:

```
List<Function<Person, Person>> rejections = Arrays.asList(
    App::rejectIfYoungerThan15, 
    App::rejectIfNameStartsWithD);

List<Person> persons1 = persons.stream()
    .map(shortCircuitReject(rejections))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: `public void reject(String comment) {
        return new Person(name, age, true, comment);
    }` would this work? I mean the `name` and the `age` assignments? You should rather let the `reject` implementation as is IMO.

Comment: Why you change the signature of reject, you can just change the p and return it back no need to change reject method

Comment: It doesn't resolve problems. You still have to check for `!p.isRejected()`  in every function and every person is still passed to every function even if it has been already rejected

Comment: @nullpointer If fixed the return type of the function. What do you mean about the `name` and `age` assignments? I don't want to leave the reject implementation as is, because it mutates the original object.

Comment: @YCF_L The point is to have `Person` immutable. You could mutate it and return the same object, but that's bad style imho.

Comment: @BorisParnikel I made an edit with a version that will short circuit.